# Get data-slug to show up

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know what I am doing wrong here but I cannot seem to display my data-slug on my site.

I want this to show up  as I have created classes based on slugs.

[what I want to show when I do inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvwED.png)

This is how I did my php-- I don't know if I had it wrong.

```
<div class="tile-wrapper">
                        <!-- TILES PER CATEGORY -->
                        <?php 
                            $tiles = get_posts( array(
                                'post_type'                 => 'artise-tiles',
                                'artise-tile-category'      => $tile_category->slug,
                                'posts_per_page'            => 10,
                                'offset'                    => 0,
                                'orderby'                   => 'name',
                                'order'                     => 'DESC'
                            ) );


                        ?>
                        <?php foreach( $tiles as $tile ): ?>
                            <?php 
                                $tile_img = get_post_meta( $tile->ID, 'artise-tile-img', true );

                                $category_terms = implode( ', ', get_terms( array(

                                    'taxonomy'              => 'artise-tile-category',
                                    'object_ids'            => $tile->ID,
                                    'fields'                => 'names'
                                ) ) );


                                $itile = array_search( $tile->ID, $curr_tile_ids );
                                $tileExists = true;

                                if( $itile === false ){
                                    $itile =  $tile_count;
                                    $tileExists = false;
                                    $curr_tile_ids []= $tile->ID;
                                }


                            ?>
                            <div
```

Comment: Looks like wordpress...

Comment: Yes. I am working on a wordpress plugin. I am getting confused as to what to do or if I am coding incorrectly which is why slug don't get pulled.